# Use local OSM server in JOSM

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

Following this tutorial (Rails Port, OpenStreetMap website) https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/INSTALL.md , I successfully installed my local server and it is working. When I go to my server adress, the website just looks like OpenStreetMap's website.

[image]

Now I want to use in JOSM my local server instead of api.openstreetmap.org/api alt text But I have this error : 
Failed to retrieve a list of changesets from the OSM API server at 'http: //localhost'. The server responded with the return code 404 instead of 200. Please check the spelling and validate again

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50063/use-local-server-in-josm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run a few internal OSM servers. There are a few things that can cause connection issues, but usually it is just a matter of the URL.

First, I assume you're not running https on your local server, so you will need to change that.

I don't think the servers run on the http port (80) by default. If not, you need to specify whichever port you're using that on the connection string.

You also need to make sure you're connecting to the API endpoint. I would expect it to look like this:
http://localhost:3000/api